# JenkinsPipelineUnit mock RunWrapper for shared library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-pipeline-unit

I've written Jenkins shared library with helpers contained code like

```
def foo() {
    ...
    return steps.build(job: jobName, wait: true, propagate: true, parameters: parameters)
}

class RunConfig implements Serializable {
    ...
    RunWrapper runWrapper
}
```

and I want to write **unit tests for them**.

It requires [`RunWrapper`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-support-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.java) mocking. And **it is a problem**, because `RunWrapper` is declared as:

```
public RunWrapper(Run<?,?> build, boolean currentBuild) {
    this.externalizableId = build.getExternalizableId();
    ...
```

so I have to create instance of `hudson.model.Run` to avoid NPE.

I don't find way to get some "dummy" `Run`. But call constructor of it is also hard way ([sources](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Run.java)) because it need in [`Job`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Job.java) instance.

Last point which I reached it is implementing `class MockJob extends Job`, `class MockItemGroup<T extends Item> implements ItemGroup` and runtime NPE from `hudson.model.Job.saveNextBuildNumber` where Job tries to create "nextBuildNumber" file in job root dir (mocked class returns `null` as root dir).

Maybe I am missing something and there is another way to test `RunWrapper`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any avaliable mocking framework (for example [mockito](http://site.mockito.org/)). And then create a mock of `RunWrapper`

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*; 
//.. 
RunWrapper runWrapperMock = mock(RunWrapper.class);
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly the same think came to my head yesterday, but Mockito can't mock it because: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper ... - final class ... I'm going to try PowerMockito at this week.

Comment: @user1535127 Since version 2.1.0 mockito supports mocking final classes. Please see http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.11.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39

Answer (score 1):

I managed to mock `RunWrapper` with PowerMockito. In "build.gradle":

```
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.1"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.1"
```

Note that `powermock-api-mockito` (i.e. 1st version) doesn't work in groovy.

In code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest([RunWrapper.class])
class BarsTest extends BasePipelineTest {
    @Test
    void fooTest() throws Exception {
        RunWrapper runWrapper = PowerMockito.mock(RunWrapper.class)
```